# Retrieving Application Data folder from Lua

Tags: lua, environment-variables

I have trouble getting Application Data in Lua. I can't even find how to do it, here on SO or anywhere else.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Application Data? Are you looking to get the value of the Windows environment variable APPDATA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the Windows application data folder, you can use:

```
os.getenv('APPDATA')
```